# Why do I get a NPE exception when nothing matches the query

Tags: java, datanucleus

Using the following datanucleus query the execute method throws a NullPointerException when nothing matches the query.

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("select avg(millis) from ");
query.append(clazz.getName());
query.append(String.format(" where name.equals('%s')", name));
query.append(String.format(" && database.equals('%s')", props.get("database")));
query.append(String.format(" && version.equals('%s')", props.get("version")));
Double ave = (Double) pm.newQuery(query.toString()).execute();
```

The NPE is as follows:

```
at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.memory.SetExpression.avg(SetExpression.java:414)
at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.memory.InMemoryExpressionEvaluator.getValueForInvokeExpression(InMemoryExpressionEvaluator.java:719)
at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.memory.InMemoryExpressionEvaluator.processInvokeExpression(InMemoryExpressionEvaluator.java:562)
at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compilePrimaryExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:200)
...
```

I spent some time in the debugger and I can see that the collection passed to the SetExpression constructor is empty.  This eventually leads to NPE in the SetExpression.avg method.

Is the correct behavior of 'avg' when the collection is empty?  The documentation is ambiguous about what the 'avg' return value would be if nothing matched the query, but I would not have expected an NPE.

Comment: How do the line numbers in the stack-trace relate to the lines of code you posted?

Comment: @DigCamara, casting `null` to a reference type never raises an NPE since `null` is a valid value for any reference type.

Comment: @Mike Samuel,Good thing I didn't mark it as an answer. Ignorance fought!

Comment: @Mike Samuel: However, wouldn't this apply: "A NullPointerException as a result of an unboxing conversion on a null reference." (from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

Comment: @DigCamara, It's possible that `ave` is unboxed later, but there's no unboxing in the code posted.  Just a lot of SQL-injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @MikeSamuel you're right about the vulnerabilities, of course. However, the exception isn't actually thrown in the lines of wytten, is it? It's within the avg function that the NPE appears. My belief would be that the avg function does some kind of unboxing because it's being asked to cast the result into Double. I haven't got any knowledge at all about the libraries involved, though.

Comment: @DigCamara, quite possibly.

Comment: @MikeSamuel sorry if the stack trace wasn't clear--The NPE happens in the datanucleus library and so the client code posted in the question calls the library and doesn't itself throw the NPE

Comment: @wytten, I understand that the last frame on the stack when the NPE occurs is in another library, but there is probably at least one stack frame in your code involved and it would help to know what that is.

Comment: @MikeSamuel it happens when I call query execute() thanks

Answer (score 0):

After lengthy discussion with @Mike Samuel, I guess this is one possible solution:

Instead of

```
Double ave = (Double) pm.newQuery(query.toString()).execute();
```

try

```
Double ave=null;
Object aveObject= pm.newQuery(query.toString()).execute();

if (aveObject!=null){
       ave=(Double)aveObject;
}
```

The error, according to the discussion, might lie in the libraries you're using which in this scenario would be trying to unbox a null value to transform it into a `Double`. Of course, it would be even better if there were no casting involved. So, if the method returns a `Float` (for instance):

```
Double ave=null;
Float aveObject= pm.newQuery(query.toString()).execute();

if (aveObject!=null){
       ave=(Double)aveObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be interpreted as a bug in datanucleus-core 3.2.13, assuming that the desired behavior of the avg projection is to return 0 if there are no selected records.

The implementation of their SetExpression.avg reads:

```
if (itemIterator == null)
{
    return 0.0d;
}
```

I'm not 100% sure but I think if that were changed to the following it would resolve the NPE in a proper way, by returning 0 if no records were selected

```
if (itemIterator == null || !iterator.hasNext())
{
    return 0.0d;
}
```

Comment: The mean is not defined for an empty list of samples.  `Double.NaN` would be a more appropriate value.

Comment: I don't disagree with you but the current code is returning 0 when the iterator is null

Comment: @whytten, Fair enough.  They have an implementation bug and possibly a specification bug.